# A RenderFlex overflowed by 117 pixels on the bottom. The relevant error-causing widget was: Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new to flutter, I was following a tutorial on how to build a flutter application. The instructors app runs well but mine throws an error

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 3.0 pixels on the bottom.The relevant
> error-causing widget was:  Column

and another error

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 117 pixels on the bottom.The relevant
> error-causing widget was: Column

the code i have

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'models/job.dart';
import 'models/global.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 225),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: new LinearGradient(
                          colors: [lightBlueIsh, lightGreen],
                          begin: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 1.0),
                          end: const FractionalOffset(0.2, 0.2),
                          stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomRight:  Radius.circular(30))
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Find Your New Job', style: titleStyleWhite,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height:200),
                  child: ListView(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: getRecentJobs()
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 500,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                        child: Text(
                          "Explore New Opportunities",
                          style: titileStyleBlack,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 400,
                        child: ListView(
                          children: getJobCategories(),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  List<String> jobCategories = ["Sales", "Engineering", "Health", "Education", "Finance"];

  Map jobCatToIcon = {
    "Sales" : Icon(Icons.monetization_on, color: lightBlueIsh, size: 50,),
    "Engineering" : Icon(Icons.settings, color: lightBlueIsh, size: 50),
    "Health" : Icon(Icons.healing, color: lightBlueIsh, size: 50),
    "Education" : Icon(Icons.search, color: lightBlueIsh, size: 50),
    "Finance" : Icon(Icons.card_membership, color: lightBlueIsh, size: 50),
  };

  Widget getCategoryContainer(String categoryName) {
    return new Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 20),
      height: 180,
      width: 140,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
        boxShadow: [
          new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey,
            blurRadius: 10.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(categoryName, style: titileStyleLighterBlack),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
            height: 100,
            width: 70,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child:  jobCatToIcon[categoryName],
              elevation: 10,
              onPressed: () {

              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getJobCategories() {
    List<Widget> jobCategoriesCards = [];
    List<Widget> rows = [];
    int i = 0;
    for (String category in jobCategories) {
      if (i < 2) {
        rows.add(getCategoryContainer(category));
        i ++;
      } else {
        i = 0;
        jobCategoriesCards.add(new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: rows,
        ));
        rows = [];
        rows.add(getCategoryContainer(category));
        i++;
      }
    }
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      jobCategoriesCards.add(new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: rows,
      ));
    }
    return jobCategoriesCards;
  }

  List<Job> findJobs() {
    List<Job> jobs = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      jobs.add(new Job("Volvo", "Frontend Developer", 20000, "Remote", "Part time", new AssetImage("lib/assets/volvo.png")));
    }
    return jobs;
  }

  String makeSalaryToK(double salary) {
    String money = "";
    if (salary > 1000) {
      if (salary > 100000000) {
        salary = salary/100000000;
        money = salary.toInt().toString() + "M";
      } else {
        salary = salary/1000;
        money = salary.toInt().toString() + "K";
      }
    } else {
      money = salary.toInt().toString();
    }
    return "\$" + money;
  }

  List<Widget> getRecentJobs() {
    List<Widget> recentJobCards = [];
    List<Job> jobs = findJobs();
    for (Job job in jobs) {
      recentJobCards.add(getJobCard(job));
    }
    return recentJobCards;
  }

  Widget getJobCard(Job job) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, bottom: 30, top: 30),
      height: 150,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            new BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey,
              blurRadius: 20.0,
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: job.companyLogo,
              ),
              Text(
                job.jobTitle,
                style: jobCardTitileStyleBlue,
              )
            ],
          ),
          Text(job.companyName + " - " + job.timeRequirement, style: jobCardTitileStyleBlack),
          Text(job.location),
          Text(makeSalaryToK(job.salary), style: salaryStyle)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change 'Column' to 'ListView'.

````
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
    ```
````

Comment: Could you add some explanation?